# mean and standard deviation of students taking a test

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, standard-deviation

6 percent of all students of a class will not pass a test. There are 450 students taking this test. Let X represent the number, out of 450 students, who will pass this test. Find the mean and standard deviation of X.

Answer (score 0):

For a size $n$ large-enough, a binomial populaion with $p=0.94$ and $q=0.06$ ( so that $p+q=1$) is approximately-normal, with mean $np=450(.94)=423$ in this case, and standard deviation $\sigma= np(1-p)= (450)(0.94)(0.06)=25.38$